# How to write append "method" in go

Tags: go

I would like to explore Go possibilities. How would you turn "append" to method? simply: "st.app(t) == append(st, t)"
This is what I got:

```
type T interface{}
type ST []interface{}
func (st []T) app (t T) []T {
    return(append(st, t))
}
```

but this code does not check for type compatibility:

```
append([]int{1,2},"a") // correctly gives error 
ST{1,2}.app("a") // dumbly gives [1 2 a] !!!
```

I know why the code does not check for type compatibility but What is the right way to do it? Is it possible?
I appreciate your help to understand how Go works.

Comment: Because Go code does not support generics, you cannot write a function that is both generic and type-safe. This is why `append` is implemented as a built-in function not as part of the stdlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is to call `append()` as the built-in function it is. It's not an accident that it's a built-in function; you can't write `append` itself in Go, and anything that approximates it would be unsafe (and over-complicated).

Don't fight Go. Just write the line of code. In the time you spend trying to create tricky generics, you could have solved three more issues and shipped the product. That's how Go works.

This isn't to say Go will never have generics, but as we move towards [Go 2](https://blog.golang.org/toward-go2) consider the following from Russ Cox:

> For example, I've been examining generics recently, but I don't have in my mind a clear picture of the detailed, concrete problems that Go users need generics to solve. As a result, I can't answer a design question like whether to support generic methods, which is to say methods that are parameterized separately from the receiver. If we had a large set of real-world use cases, we could begin to answer a question like this by examining the significant ones.

(On the other hand, Generics is the most responded-to topic in [ExperienceReports](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/ExperienceReports#generics), so it's not that no one is aware of the interest. But don't fight Go. It's a fantastic language for shipping great software. It is not, however, a generic language.)

Comment: Thanks. I got it. After years of coding in generic languages (Python, R, JS,..) it is hard to get used to Go. But I like most of its ideas and simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

4 years later, there is actually a possible solution to get methods that are parameterized separately from the receiver.

1. There is with [Go 1.18 generics](https://go.dev/blog/generics-proposal)
2. It does [*not* support parameterized method](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#no-parameterized-methods)
3. It *does* support parameterized method, meaning the receiver may have type parameters
4. [Jaana B. Dogan](https://twitter.com/rakyll) proposes "[Generics facilitators in Go](https://rakyll.org/generics-facilititators/)" based on that

> Parameterized receivers are a useful tool and helped me develop a common pattern, facilitators, to overcome the shortcomings of having no parameterized methods.
> Facilitators are simply a new type that has access to the type you wished you had generic methods on.

[Her example](https://go.dev/play/p/junNJF4p-dF?v=gotip):

```golang
package database

type Client struct{ ... }

type Querier[T any] struct {
    client *Client
}

func NewQuerier[T any](c *Client) *Querier[T] {
    return &Querier[T]{
        client: c,
    }
}

func (q *Querier[T]) All(ctx context.Context) ([]T, error) {
    // implementation
}

func (q *Querier[T]) Filter(ctx context.Context, filter ...Filter) ([]T, error) {
    // implementation
```

You can use it as:

```
querier := database.NewQuerier[Person](client)
```

In your case though, while you could define an `Appender` struct, it still needs to apply on a concrete struct, which is why using the built-in `append()` remains preferable.

But in general, should you need parameterized methods, Jaana's pattern can help.